# When saving as JPG or PNG in Illustrator, do I need to convert text to outlines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, png, jpg

In Illustrator, when I create an artwork that includes text, I'm never sure if I need to convert the text to outlines before exporting as PNG or JPG.

Is this text automatically converted to curves when a PNG or JPG file is created? Or are the original text & font retained? Basically, I want to know if the text in the final image will look the same for everyone, regardless of fonts used in the original artwork if I *don't* convert to outlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is - absolutely no need to convert text to curves if you're saving as JPG/PNG.

Longer answer is: JPG/PNG are raster formats - when you export, the image will be "flattened" and no information of the font whatsoever will be preserved. Everyone will see the same result. The design will be like a photo - a photo might have signs and text, but it's not understood as such.

Convert to curves is useful mostly when you're giving a file to a printing house, and formats most commonly associated would be EPS and AI.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, @SpasimirDinev! That's what I suspected, but I couldn't find absolute confirmation anywhere online. Will stop converting text-to-curves from now on before saving as JPG/PNG.